# setting and using owne variable in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, global-variables

I set variable in .htaccess like this

```
SetEnv clubhub_path clubhub-ui
```

And I can acces it in php with

```
$_SERVER['clubhub_path];
```

But I wanted to use it in .htaccess in Rewrite Cond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/%{SERVER:clubhub_path}/media/).+ [NC]
```

I found somewhere this(%{SERVER:clubhub_path}) should work but it doesn't. I tried all the combinations with {}, %, $. No success...

Cheers

Comment: I think you are looking for `%{ENV:clubhub_path}` since the `SetEnv` sets environment variables.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work either... Maybe I need to enable something in my apache conf?

Comment: Not sure, but since this "clubhub_path" is in the same file, couldn't you just write it into directly to the `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Yeah, I could, but: 1. it's in many rules; 2. now I'm really curious how to achieve that;)

Answer (score 0):

`SetEnv` sets environment variables, so it should be available in `%{ENV:clubhub_path}` but i've tried that and doesn't seem to be working.

However since you can set environment variables with `RewriteRule`s you could write it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [E=clubhub_path:clubhub-ui]
```

This rule matches every url, but doesn't rewrite it to anyting just sets an environment variable that will be available in `RewriteCond`s like:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:clubhub_path} ^clubhub-ui$
```

This should look like exactly the same once it gets to php. (in `$_SERVER` superglobal, or `getenv()`)

### Update

However you still can't use your `%{ENV:variable}` in the right hand side of `RewriteCond`. I think the only way to do this if you are on apache 2.4 and you can use [ap_expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)

```
RewriteCond expr "! '%{REQUEST_URI}' -strcmatch '/%{ENV:clubhub_path}/media/*'"
```

In my test environment this seem to be doing what you want (negative match on the '/clubhub-ui/media' urls, but apache2.4 is still pretty new, you probably can't have it installed if you are not self-hosted.

Maybe [RewriteMap with a `prg`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg) parameter and a script could implement your idea.

Comment: But I wish to use it like this RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/%{ENV:clubhub_path}/media/).+ [NC], doesn't seem to work...