# Create and use your own variables in apache .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, variables, global-variables

Briefly to my somewhat unusual question, to which I have unfortunately not yet found a suitable answer in the vastness of the Internet:

**I would like to define a local variable in an Apache (2.4) `.htaccess`-file and also use it in the same file, i.e. read it.**

I have also seen other contributions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922089/setting-and-using-owne-variable-in-htaccess). However, I don't want to use the variable in `RewriteCond`, but as in the example below.

**Initial situation**: I have a static path that I often have to place in front of various relative paths. This problem prevents me from adding the path manually ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)). I would like to avoid this redundancy and fall back on the concept of variables.

`.htaccess`

```
# however variables are defined
VAR_TO_PATH = "/abs/path/to/"

# use of the variable
AuthUserFile VAR_TO_PATH."/htdata/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile VAR_TO_PATH."/htdata/.htgroup"
```

Can anyone help me with my requirements?

*Cheers*

#### already tested unsatisfied

`.htaccess`

```
# definition of variables
SetEnv root_path "C:/xampp/htdocs/my/"

# use of the variable
AuthUserFile "%{SERVER:root_path}htdata/.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile "%{ENV:root_path}htdata/.htgroup"
```

`error.log`

```
[Sun Nov 12 21:53:56.703673 2023] [core:alert] [pid 20688:tid 1900] [client 127.0.0.1:51989] C:/xampp/htdocs/my/.htaccess: AuthUserFile: Invalid file path '%{ENV:root_path}.htdata/.htpasswd'

[Sun Nov 12 21:54:11.942883 2023] [core:alert] [pid 20688:tid 1900] [client 127.0.0.1:52011] C:/xampp/htdocs/my/.htaccess: AuthGroupFile: Invalid file path '%{SERVER:root_path}.htdata/.htgroup'
```

Comment: I am not aware of such feature in the rewriting module. You can refer environment variables, that is the way to go. The answer you referred to above is not limited to a `RewriteCond`. You should be able to use it for your purpose too.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you very much for your advice. I have included my test above. Unfortunately, I have no success, not even with your suggestion. Have you been able to verify this for yourself?

Comment: No, I have not verified that myself, sorry. It has been a long time since I last worked in that field. In general environment variables need to have UPPERCASE names. And have a try using `%{ENV:ROOT_PATH}` ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not (yet?) possible using `.htaccess` alone for these particular directives (you would need access to the server config), for a couple of reasons:

- `AuthUserFile` (part of mod_authn_file) and `AuthGroupFile` (part of mod_authz_groupfile) do not (yet?) support [expression syntax](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) that would allow the referencing of environment variables (either imported from the OS or set with `SetEnvIf`) using syntax of the form `%{reqenv:VARIABLE}`. (In later versions of Apache 2.4, a number of modules/directives have been updated to allow this syntax, but not the directives in question unfortunately.)
- You need access to the main server config (eg. `<VirtualHost>` container) in order to `Define` server variables that can be used in other config directives. If you have access to the server config then you can [`Define`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#define) variables that can be used in any config directive using the syntax `${VARIABLE}` - these are parsed *early*, so are not dependent on the directive in question.

  For example:

  ```
  # Main server config
  <VirtualHost: *443>
      Define VAR_TO_PATH /abs/path/to/
      :
  ```

  ---

  ```
  # .htaccess
  AuthUserFile ${VAR_TO_PATH}/htdata/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile ${VAR_TO_PATH}/htdata/.htgroup
  ```

However, neither of these options are really considered "local" variables. Environment variables are "local" to the *environment* and `Define`'d server variables are arguably "global" (they are set in a "localised" container, such as the `<VirtualHost>` or `<Directory>` but are then accessible outside of that container).

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> # definition of variables
> SetEnv root_path "C:/xampp/htdocs/my/"
> ```

Regarding the use of `SetEnv` (mod_env) to set environment variables. This directive (module) is processed very *late*. Too late to be picked up by most other configuration directives. If you need to set an environment variable to be used by other directives then you nearly always need to use [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) (mod_setenvif) instead, which is processed *early*.

(You can also set env vars using mod_rewrite, `RewriteRule`, which is also processed *early*, but later than `SetEnvIf`. Unless you are primarily using mod_rewrite, or have a complex conditional, you would not use mod_rewrite over mod_setenvif to set env vars.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the informative and very good explanation! Then all I can do at the moment is hope and submit a feature request. Am I reading this correctly, that the paths for "AuthUserFile" as well as for "AddIcon" or "ErrorDocument" must always be absolute? I've only had problems with relative paths so far...